# Calculating the week day, by entering specific date

Tags: java, calendar

I need to create a program which shows the day of week, when you enter the specific date to console.

Here's the code I've written, but still not working, why would it be?

```
public class CalculateDay{

     public static void main(String []args){


         int m = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
         int d = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
         int y = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

         System.out.println("Finding day of week for "+m+"-"+d+"-"+y);


         int yo = y - ((14-m)/12);

         int x = yo + yo/4 - yo/100 + yo/400;

         int mo = m + 12*((14-m)/12) -2;

         int dayOfWeek = (d + x + (31*mo)/12)%7;

         String dayString;

         switch(dayOfWeek){
            case 0:    dayString = "Sunday";
                        break;
            case 1:    dayString = "Monday";
                        break;
            case 2:    dayString = "Tuesday";
                        break;
            case 3:    dayString = "Wednesday";
                        break;
            case 4:    dayString = "Thursday";
                        break;
            case 5:    dayString = "Friday";
                        break;
            case 6:    dayString = "Saturday";
                        break;            
            default:    dayString = "Could not find";
         }

        System.out.println(dayString);
     }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it *should* work? What do you think you are calculating here? What input are you giving, what output do you get, what do you expect?

Comment: You can calculate the Julian day number from a Gregorian date [using the method described here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_date#Converting_Julian_or_Gregorian_calendar_date_to_Julian_day_number). There are hints of this method in your code (e.g. `(14-m)/12` and `yo/4 - yo/100 + yo/400`), but it is not quite the same. Perhaps try that method, see if you can get the right answer.

Comment: I have a basic Gregorian Calendar calculation above, then I used switch construct(as it demanded by assignment). I definitely did something wrong, but I just couldn't find it. Thanks for your advise, I'll be looking at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
int m = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
int d = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
int y = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

System.out.println("Finding day of week for "+m+"-"+d+"-"+y);

Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(y, m, d);
System.out.println("DAY_OF_WEEK: " + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
```